# Emacs syntax highlighting for making a term with boolean operators more readable?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

I have a long string with boolean logic like

("Mercedes Benz" or "Audi" not "Volkswagen" not "truck")  but much longer and more complex (with several parenthesis etc.)

I wonder how I can make this string more readable for me and others, I think indenting and coloring could help.

Is there a way to format this string automatically with emacs to make reading it easier?

Example string (which does not necessarily makes sense logically!)

> ("Mercedes Benz" or (Benz not Carl not Carl* not female )  or "Daimler
>   Chrysler" or "Daimler corporation" or daimler or chrysler or amg or
>   car or automobile or automotive or "automo* manufactur*" )

Operators:

- and
- or
- not
- nor
- xor

Text strings

- like that: `"Daimler Chrysler"`
- or just words like `daimler` `Benz` etc.

Wildcards:

- *

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Syntax highlighting is available but depends on the language. What language are you using? Elisp?

Comment: not really. It is a search term like used for a search engine (similar to google) to filter interesting content. It looks very similar to elisp, so maybe a syntax highlighting and formatting (with line breaks and indentation) for elisp could help. Unfortunately, I can not paste the real example here.

Answer (score 1):

Defining font-locking can be tricky. You would need to post an example of the syntax you want highlighted, even if a pseudo-example. Keep in mind too that if you want to highlight keywords such as `or` and `and` then, because these can often be part of larger terms, you will need a regular expression that can distinguish these when they are being used as keywords. E.g., is whitespace enough to distinguish them in your context?

In sum, give an example --- we cannot guess the syntax you are trying to work with.

Comment: thanks for your help! I've added a longer example string which should cover all general syntax